# ASIO Debug Error in MSVC Debug Build- No error in Release Build

Tags: visual-c++, boost-asio

A simple tcp client using ASIO causes abort() to be called for Debug builds. The same application in Release build works without throwing an error. The compiler is Visual Studio 2017.

Attaching a debugger to the application does not provide any additional information.

A demonstration example that takes the port as a command line argument that connects to server and disconnects immediately is shown below.

Any way I can avoid this error in the debug build?

```cxx
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "asio.hpp"

using asio::ip::tcp;

class Client {
  std::unique_ptr<asio::io_service> io_service_ = nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<tcp::socket> sock_ = nullptr;

 public:
  Client() {
    io_service_ = std::make_unique<asio::io_service>();
    sock_ = std::make_unique<tcp::socket>(*io_service_);
  }
  void connect(std::string hostname, unsigned int port) {
    auto resolver = tcp::resolver(*io_service_);
    auto query = tcp::resolver::query(hostname, std::to_string(port));
    auto endpoint_iter = resolver.resolve(query);
    asio::connect(*sock_, endpoint_iter);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  try {
    auto port = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    Client client;
    client.connect("localhost", port);
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "\n" << e.what();
  }
}
```

Comment: "Attaching a debugger to the application does not provide any additional information." How not? There will always at least be a stacktrace at the point of `abort()`. You can even set a breakpoint on the library function itself in case the debugger catches it too late

Comment: @sehe There is no trace when I have the try-catch blocks, when I take out the try-catch blocks I get a trace > sClient.exe!invoke_main() Line 79 C++
  sClient.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 288 C++
  sClient.exe!__scrt_common_main() Line 331 C++
  sClient.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 17 C++
  kernel32.dll!00007ff95ae43034() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!00007ff95b071431() Unknown

That I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

The common source of these are debug iterators. They're your friend, because they warn you about Undefined Behaviour in your program.

In this program, I see no such issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class Client {
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service_ = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<tcp::socket> sock_ = nullptr;

  public:
    Client() {
        io_service_ = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service>();
        sock_ = std::make_unique<tcp::socket>(*io_service_);
    }
    void connect(std::string hostname, unsigned int port) {
        auto resolver = tcp::resolver(*io_service_);
        auto query = tcp::resolver::query(hostname, std::to_string(port));
        auto endpoint_iter = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::connect(*sock_, endpoint_iter);
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        Client client;
        client.connect("localhost", 6767);
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "\n" << e.what();
    }
}
```

The chief difference is that I'm not using `argv[1]`. Since you didn't check `argc`, did you in fact pass arguments for the Debug configuration?

Comment: I am in fact passing arguments to the debug config and see the value while stepping through the code while debugging. The Client is part of a bigger library that was causing this error and I had isolated to this part, the server uses a random port so it was convenient to have it as a command line argument for the client. I do not know much about debug iterators, a quick doc search [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=vs-2017) showed I could set _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0. Setting this did not suppress the issue.

Comment: Good luck isolating the bug further, then!